# Java Wrong trendline calculation

Tags: java, math

I have a problem. I was trying to use this package to calculate a slope of a trendline: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17634728/10673107. So I have the following main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long[] arrOpenTime = new Long[] {0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L};
    double[] arrData = new double[] {62950.326, 62996.7789, 63021.8868, 63073.9042, 63064.8436, 63028.78, 63014.8, 62806.0692, 62651.2262, 62467.2976};
    getTrendline(arrData, arrOpenTime, 10L);
}
```

And here is the function `getTrendLine()`:

```
private static void getTrendline(double[] data, Long[] openTimes, long timestampToPredict) {

    // Start a regression class of order 2--linear regression.
    PolyTrendLine polyTrendLine = new PolyTrendLine(2);

    // Add all the data to the regression analysis.
    polyTrendLine.setValues(data, openTimes);

    // Get coefficients for the polynomial.
    System.out.println(polyTrendLine.predict(timestampToPredict));
    System.out.println(polyTrendLine.getCoef());
    
}
```

Now I would have expected that the `getCoef()` would have printed the slope of the trendline (in my case: `-48.84`), but I get the following:

```
Array2DRowRealMatrix{{62915.24316},{110.2559048485},{-17.6773151515}}
```

I don't know if this package is capable of what I want, because my main goal is to get all values to create the forumla. The correct formula for these given values is:
[image]

How can I calculate the values:

- Slope: `-48.84`
- Intercept-Y: `63127`

using an array of data points.
Please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SO answer you've linked is simply a wrapper around the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) stats package. But you don't need that wrapper, your problem is simple enough to use that package directly:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression;

public class Regression {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] data = {
            {0.0, 62950.326},
            {1.0, 62996.7789},
            {2.0, 63021.8868},
            {3.0, 63073.9042},
            {4.0, 63064.8436},
            {5.0, 63028.78},
            {6.0, 63014.8},
            {7.0, 62806.0692},
            {8.0, 62651.2262},
            {9.0, 62467.2976}
        };

        SimpleRegression regression = new SimpleRegression();
        regression.addData(data);
        regression.regress();

        System.out.println(regression.getSlope());
        System.out.println(regression.getIntercept());
    }
}
```